# How to programatically launch N programs in N screen sessions?

Tags: bash, script, shell-script, gnu-screen, bash-scripting

I want to create single bash script that will start N apps in N detached screen sessions - I mean something like this:

```
1. create screen session
2. launch app A
3. detach screen
4. create another screen session
5. launch app B
6. detach
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-d -m` option combo to start a command in a detached screen:

```
for i in {1..10} ; do
    screen -d -m app $i
done
```